# MSSQL procedure to insert data in a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert, sql-server-express

I'm trying to create a procdeure to insert data in a table, but there is an error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertBOOKS
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @BookName varchar(30),
    @Author_ID INT,
    @Quantity INT,
    @Genre_ID INT,
    @BookID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO BOOKS
    (BOOK_NAME, BOOK_AUTHOR_ID, QUANTITY, BOOK_GENRE_ID)
    VALUES (@BookName, @Author_ID, @Quantity, @Genre_ID);

SET @BookID = @@IDENTITY
END



DECLARE @return_value int,
        @BookID int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[InsertBOOKS]
        @BookName = N'Jopa',
        @Author_ID = 1,
        @Quantity = 2,
        @Genre_ID = 3,
        @BookID = @BookID OUTPUT

SELECT  @BookID as N'@BookID'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

0 ideas how to fix it

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what you expect from return_value, but to get the last inserted id, you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
CREATE tABLe BOOKS
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),BOOK_NAME varchar(100), BOOK_AUTHOR_ID int, QUANTITY int, BOOK_GENRE_ID int)
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertBOOKS
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @BookName varchar(30),
    @Author_ID INT,
    @Quantity INT,
    @Genre_ID INT,
    @BookID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO BOOKS
    (BOOK_NAME, BOOK_AUTHOR_ID, QUANTITY, BOOK_GENRE_ID)
    VALUES (@BookName, @Author_ID, @Quantity, @Genre_ID);

SET @BookID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @BookID int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[InsertBOOKS]
        @BookName = N'Jopa',
        @Author_ID = 1,
        @Quantity = 2,
        @Genre_ID = 3,
        @BookID = @BookID OUTPUT

SELECT  @BookID as N'@BookID'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

| @BookID |
| --- |
| 1 |

| Return Value |
| --- |
| 0 |

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS
```

| ID | BOOK_NAME | BOOK_AUTHOR_ID | QUANTITY | BOOK_GENRE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jopa | 1 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_i-8vDFc)

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` docs: *"The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope."* so bad idea. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `OUTPUT` are the only solutions that work.